# Movie with an Indian girl helping a willow tree and a horse after playing with the personified wind; other girl is punished for doing the opposite

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a long shot, but my cousin had a VHS movie that we used to watch over and over when we were young... during the 2000's. I think her mom had gotten it as a gift or probably as a donation.

It was about two Indian girls (a nice one and a bad one)... and one day the wind, (which was portrayed as a little boy) came to play with the nice girl and started to lead her down the road.

The nice girl then ends up with a horse who is in trouble, and if I recall correctly she helps him get water from a well. She then keeps going on her path and finds a willow tree, and she does something good there but I can't remember.

Anyway, then she ends up going up on a cloud...? Not sure, but she ends up on the moon. It's beautiful up there and theres also a mystical lagoon up there and a castle. Nobody appears to be home so she starts poking around and ends up taking a dip in the water. As soon as she gets up she notices she is covered in jewelry. Then there's like a grandma and she is spying on her. The girl then takes a box and leaves the moon.The girl goes back to her mom and shows her all the blessings she found on her journey.

The bad girl does the same thing except she doesn't help the horse, or the tree. When she lands on the moon she dips twice and takes two boxes... basically she is portrayed as greedy... so in the end I believe the boxes she takes home are cursed.

Comment: Hi there! That's some very good info already but could you please take a look at [those guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Just to check - was that a live-action movie or a cartoon/anime?

Comment: Indians as in 'from India' or Indians as in 'Cowboys and...'?

Comment: Also - do you know where this movie was made? Or seemed to have been made? (sounds like a Hindi movie could be made with such a plot, hence me asking :) )

Answer (score 10):

This is the plot of [**Deepa & Rupa: A Fairy Tale from India**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2014206/), a 30 minute short from 1990. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepa_%26_Rupa:_A_Fairy_Tale_from_India):

> Two stepsisters, Deepa and Rupa, have different personalities. Deepa is selfish, Rupa is kind. The personified 'wind' steals their cotton, forcing the sisters to go to the old woman in the moon. Along the way they encounter a number of magical creatures, including a horse, a cow, and a banyan tree, all needing their help. Each sister's actions contribute to their ultimately different fates, teaching children the morals of kindness and service to others as well as respect for nature.

Its creator (Manick Sorcar) published the whole thing on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S1nzXza1OIs) and here's an image with that thirsty horse, from [his website](http://www.manicksorcar.com/):

[image]

Comment: This was originally a story from the children's book Tinkle - the title of the story was Saku and Daku.

Comment: Sounds a lot like the Grimm's fairy tale "Mother Hulda."

Comment: [Mother Hulda.](https://www.grimmstories.com/language.php?grimm=024&l=en&r=de)